# ¿como obtengo los valores de mi variable tipo array en js?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

quiero obtener los valores de mi variable por separado hice un console para que vean como aparece
[image: aqui la imagen]

codigo:

```
$scope._nuevaSolicitud=data.lstResultado[0];

console.log("esta es mi variable",$scope._nuevaSolicitud);
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

Hola Miguel se debe llamar por los nombres de los campos recibidos:

```
let direccion = $scope._nuevaSolicitud.direccion;
let estatus= $scope._nuevaSolicitud.estatus
let folio_os_comercial = $scope._nuevaSolicitud.folio_os_comercial 
let nombre_cliente = $scope._nuevaSolicitud.nombre_cliente 
let servicio = $scope._nuevaSolicitud.servicio 
let telefono = $scope._nuevaSolicitud.telefono
```

espero te ayude saludos.

Comment: $scope.properties.nombreClientem=$scope._nuevaSolicitud.nombre_cliente;                  $scope.properties.direccionClientem=$scope._nuevaSolicitud.direccion;                    $scope.properties.estatusCliente=$scope._nuevaSolicitud.estatus;                 $scope.properties.folioOsComercial=$scope._nuevaSolicitud.folio_os_comercial;
$scope.properties.telefonoCliente=$scope._nuevaSolicitud.telefono;                    
$scope.properties.productoCliente=$scope._nuevaSolicitud.servicio;

Comment: muchas gracias bro me sirvio de ejemplo tu ayuda y así quedo para hacerlo funcional.